# How to access source code in Mac OS?

Tags: python, add-on, command-line, osx, source-code

[image]

I want to open Blender **source code** file for studying more details. There's a [YT video](https://youtu.be/bZUTiAJ1Tuc?list=PLa1F2ddGya_8acrgoQr1fTeIuQtkSd6BW&t=68) for doing this, but it's about 2 years old and on my laptop, somewhat reason, Blender can't open the file then spits this error;

> Active button is not from a script. cannot edit source

According to the [API docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html), I opened Blender with bunch of command lines, but nothing changes;

```
./Blender --env-system-scripts BLENDER_SYSTEM_SCRIPTS --env-system-datafiles BLENDER_SYSTEM_DATAFILES
```

I entered *Package Contents* of Blender for finding built-in files directly, and then again, there's no module `_bpy` in any of folders.

`__init__.py` file on VSC;

```
../3.1/scripts/modules/bpy

# internal blender C module
from _bpy import (
    app,
    context,
    data,
    msgbus,
    props,
    types,
)

** Import "_bpy" could not be resolved Pylance reportMissingImports **

reportMissingImports    Diagnostics for imports that have no corresponding imported python file or type stub file.
```

I'm using v3.1.2 and haven't changed anything from the factory setting except Developer Tool on Preference for showing `edit source`.

Are there any tips for resolving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't Python source code for all of the UI, and the message "**not from a script**" is telling you that the button you're currently interested in was generated in C rather than Python.  Unfortunately, the developer tools for looking at source from within Blender only works for Python code.

You can look at the C code, but it is much harder to track down the specifics because you need to know something about how the Blender C code interacts with the Python code.  You can find the C code, as well as the Python code, at the [official Blender github mirror](https://github.com/blender).

I can't tell from your screenshot what button you were hovering over when you clicked, so I can't really give you pointers to a specific bit of C code and how to find the C code is a tutorial that needs writing but isn't really available.

Comment: In the image I right clicked on `Sclae Z` property but all the props are basically having the same lists except the dimensions.

Comment: Oh nvm. I was wrong. He chose 3D Cursor prop in his video, not the Transforms. Now it works fine.